# Dirac distribution on a manifold $M$ as a smooth manifold in $C^1(M)^*$, question about its dimension

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, elliptic-pde

I have not learned many knowledges on differential geometry, I met this when trying to read the min-max scheme in PDE on manifold, which is in [Section3.1](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410141).

Let $M_1= \delta_{x_i}$, $x_i \in M$. For $\|f\|_{C^1(M)} \leq 1$, the distance on $M_1$ is defined by $$
\operatorname{dist}(\sigma, \hat{\sigma})=\sup _f|(\sigma, f)-(\hat{\sigma}, f)|
.$$
Didier in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4794362/the-dirac-distribution-on-a-manifold-m-is-a-smooth-manifold-in-c1m-wha) kindly taught me that by the embedding $M \rightarrow C^1(M)^*$ given by $x \mapsto \delta_x$, $M_1$ is a smooth manifold in $C^1(M)^*$.
Then they set $M_1(\varepsilon):=M_1$ . And $M_k=\sum_{i=1}^k t_i \delta_{x_i}$ with $\sum_i t_i=1$, and for $j<k$, $d_j(\sigma)=\operatorname{dist}\left(\sigma, M_j\right), \sigma \in M_k$, then for $\varepsilon>0$ and $2 \leq j \leq k$, define $$M_j(\varepsilon)=\left\{\sigma \in M_j: d_{j-1}(\sigma)>\varepsilon\right\}.$$ Then they said element of $M_j(\varepsilon)$ can be smoothly parameterized by $4 j$ coordinates locating the points $x_i$ 's and by $j-1$ coordinates identifying the numbers $t_i$ 's.

This is a corollary of [Lemma3.2](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410141), which said that

**Lemma 3.2 Let $j \in\{2, \ldots, k\}$. Then there exists $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small with the following property. If $\sigma \in M_j(\varepsilon), \sigma=\sum_{i=1}^j t_i \delta_{x_i}$, then there holds
$$
t_i \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} ; \quad \operatorname{dist}\left(x_i, x_l\right) \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} ; \quad i, l=1, \ldots, j, i \neq l .
$$**

At first I think this $4j$ depends on the dimension 4 of the manifold, but I find another paper using this notation on surface, which also said that it is $4 j$ [EXISTENCE RESULT FOR THE MEAN FIELD PROBLEM ON RIEMANN SURFACES OF ALL GENUSES](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219199708002776?journalCode=ccm), I wonder how to calculate this $4 j$.

Comment: I am a bit confused. The distance you define looks like a distance in $C^0(M)^*$ that does not care at all for the position of points, only for the weights $t_i$. Is that true? So $M_1$ is a discrete set. Also I do not see where differentiability of $f$ is needed. In fact the simple answer could be that working in $C^0(M)^*$ in a 4-manifold, you need $4j$ coordinates. And working in $C^1(M)^*$ where $M$ is a surface, you need $4j$ coordinates if you replace $\delta_{x_i}$ by evaluation of a directional derivative at a given point. Could you revise your question to make all this a bit clearer?